# Why does \today crash in Tufte-LaTeX using 'isodate' when passed as an argument?

Tags: tufte, datetime, isodate

I'm trying to use the `isodate` package with Tufte-LaTeX, but get

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
```

when I use `\today` as an argument to certain functions (e.g. `\printdate` or `\allcaps`):

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-handout}    
\usepackage[iso,american]{isodate}    
\begin{document}    
\allcaps{\today}    
\end{document}
```

If `\date` is set, I get a different error

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has extra }.
```

Using `\protect\today` fixes the above, but I still get the errors when I try to use the date as I need to:

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-handout}    
\usepackage[iso,american]{isodate}    
\date{\protect\today}
%\date{5/16/1961} % Works fine if a date is provided
\begin{document} 
\makeatletter   
\printdate{\@date}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\protect\today` instead of `\today` (I can't test right now).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Thanks, that gets me part way there, but I still can't do what I need to do (see edit to question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default definition of `\@date` and `\date` is

```
\def\@date{\today}
\def\date#1{\gdef\@date{#1}}
```

This is not changed by `isodate`, which however redefines `\today`. You can check if the user has said `\date{...}` with

```
\def\kernel@date{\today}
\ifx\@date\kernel@date
  <what to do if no \date command has been given>
\else
  <what to do if \date has been given>
\fi
```

Of course if one says `\date{21 marzo 2012}`, `\printdate` would have a hard time in producing the date in correct form with

```
\printdate{\csname @date\endcsname}
```

(this is the same as `\makeatletter\printdate{\@date}\makeatother`, but more economical).

Comment: This produces "<what to do if \date has been given>" _always_ (for no `\date` call, for `\date{}`, for `date{\protect\today}`, and for `\date{14/10/1066}`).

Comment: For the above to work: `\makeatletter \def\kernel@date{\protect\today}`.

Answer (score 3):

Bruno's answer of using `\protect\today` works for the `\allcaps` treatment (though I'm not sure why you'd want to print an ISO-format date with that spacing).

You can't use `\today` as an argument to `\printdate`. It needs to be in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, `mm.dd.yyyy`, or `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage[iso,american]{isodate}

\begin{document}

\allcaps{\protect\today}% <-- added \protect

\printdate{2012/03/20}
\printdate{20.03.2012}
\printdate{20/03/2012}

\end{document}
```

Based on the comments below, here's a more complete solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[iso,american]{isodate}

\makeatletter
% Set default date to today's date (in ISO format)
\xdef\@date{\the\year-\the\month-\the\day}

% Helper macro to avoid @s in macro name
\newcommand{\thedate}{\@date}

% Helper macro to avoid more typing
\newcommand{\printthedate}{\printdate{\@date}}
\makeatother

% Optionally change the date
%\date{2010-01-31}% must be in ISO format

\begin{document}

% Prints the date set by \date or today's date by default
\printdate{\thedate}

% Same as above
\printthedate

\end{document}
```

First, we redefine `\@date` to be today's date (using the ISO format). This means that if `\date` isn't specified, we'll default to today's date.

Next, we've written a `\thedate` helper macro.  This just saves us some typing in the document. Without this macro, we'd have to write `\makeatletter\printdate{\@date}\makeatother` instead of `\printdate{\thedate}`.  Additionally, we've created a `\printthedate` macro that is equivalent to `\printdate{\thedate}`.  (Yes, I'm a lazy typist!)

If you want to use a date other than today's date, you must specify it using in ISO format `\date{yyyy-mm-dd}` (or one of the other formats supported by the `\printdate` macro).

Finally, the document demonstrates the helper macros.

Comment: Thanks, see addition to question above. What I'm trying to do, FWIW, is use the current date if none is specified, and otherwise use the specified date (in whatever form it is entered) to print out the date in whatever format has been selected for the `isodate` package (which might not be the ISO date format).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Can't you just use `\today` then? It'll print the current date in ISO format. If you want a date other than today's date, use `\printdate`.

Comment: Yes, but I can only do that if I know that `\date{}` hasn't been set (or is "today"). I'm not sure how to do either (by testing `\@date`).

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide an example of what you'd like to write (code) and what the result should be (for both the case where `\date` is `\today` and the case where it's set to something else)?  That'll give us an idea of what you're really trying to do.

Comment: When the date has been set by using `\date{...}`, I want to print that date in the format specified by `isodate`; when it hasn't been set (there's no `\date`) I want to print the current date in that format. If I could detect which of these two has occurred, I could use `\today` (or `\protect\today`) in the latter case and `\printdate{\@date}` in the former. (But [this method](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48759/7844) for distinguishing does not work.)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to precise that `Tufte classes` redefine some macros

First  `\newcommand{\thedate}{\today}`

and

```
\renewcommand*{\date}[1]{%
  \gdef\@date{#1}%
  \begingroup%
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}% swallow \thanks contents
    \protected@xdef\thedate{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
```

I think you need to take care of these modifications and you can define an iso format without ìsodate` package.